# When there is common processing that property names and values ​to be assigned are different, their smart grouping method

Tags: javascript

I wrote JavaScript that hovers between two elements. But it was much longer than I think.

This code has many things in common, such as styling, so I thought it could be improved to be shorter and easier to understand.
However, I do not know how to improve this.

```js
// It's very long and has duplicate processing.

document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("mouseenter", event => {
    let index = [
      ...document.querySelector(".wrap_square > ul.square_list").children
    ].findIndex(c => c == event.target.parentNode);
    if (event.target.tagName === "A") {
      index = [...document.querySelectorAll(".wrap_list > ul.list_list")]
        .map(e => [...e.children])
        .flat()
        .findIndex(c => c == event.target.parentNode);
    }

    if (event.target.tagName === "A") {
      event.target.style.color = "#E91E63";
      document.querySelectorAll(".square_list li > .btn")[
          index
        ].style.backgroundColor =
        "rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.71)";
    } else {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.71)";
      document.querySelectorAll(".list_list li > a")[index].style.color =
        "#E91E63";
    }
  });
  btn.addEventListener("mouseleave", event => {
    let index = [
      ...document.querySelector(".wrap_square > ul.square_list").children
    ].findIndex(c => c == event.target.parentNode);
    if (event.target.tagName === "A") {
      index = [...document.querySelectorAll(".wrap_list > ul.list_list")]
        .map(e => [...e.children])
        .flat()
        .findIndex(c => c == event.target.parentNode);
    }

    if (event.target.tagName === "A") {
      event.target.style.color = "";
      document.querySelectorAll(".square_list li > .btn")[
          index
        ].style.backgroundColor =
        "";
    } else {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = "";
      document.querySelectorAll(".list_list li > a")[index].style.color = "";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.area_map {
  height: 20vh;
}

.btn {
  width: 6vw;
  height: 2vh;
  border: 1px solid;
}

li+li {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p class="title">Hover square or link</p>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrap_square">
      <ul class="square_list">
        <li>
          <div class="btn"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btn"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btn"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btn"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btn"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btn"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btn"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btn"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap_list">
      <ul class="list_list left">
        <li><a href="#" class="btn">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn">four</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="list_list right">
        <li><a href="#" class="btn">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn">six</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn">seven</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn">eight</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I eliminate these common areas and make the code easier to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write it as:

```
   const $ = selector => [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
   const on = (target, type, handler) => target.forEach(it => it.addEventListener(type, handler));

   const highlight = button => {
      for(const button of buttons)
        button.style.color = button === target ? "#E91E63" : "";
   };

   const buttons = $(".square_list > .btn"), links = $(".wrap_list > .btn");

   on(buttons, "mouseenter", ({ target }) => {
     highlight(target);
   });

   on(links, "click", ({ target }) => {
     const buttonTarget = buttons[ links.indexOf(target) ];
     highlight(buttonTarget);
   });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The idea was very helpful.